# Repeating function in python?

Tags: python

For my own personal enjoyment I like to just throw scripts together and make them look cool, but in this case I am trying to find a repeating command/function in python so I don't have to copy and paste 600 lines of code. I am using the while True: command but after a couple of repeats I need it to stop so I can move on with the rest of the script. What line could I use to do that without a ton of copying and pasting?

Comment: What does your current code look like? Please edit a short example that demonstrates what you are trying to do into your post (without too much detail that isn't relevant to the current question).

Comment: do you need it to stop on command or just do the same action a certain amount of times?

Comment: the other guy solved it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: take a look at loops. `FOR, WHILE, DO WHILE`. Please Google before asking Question. I don't have the permission to down vote your Q. -1 for your Q man.

Comment: Erm, your comment really has nothing to do with what I am asking. I know what while loops are, but I was asking for how to repeat them for a certain amount of times.

Comment: You can make your `WHILE` loops repeat for certain amount of time by adding a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print "chunky bacon"
...
chunky bacon
chunky bacon
chunky bacon
chunky bacon
chunky bacon
```

Answer (score 0):

since you already started with while loop, you can use a counter to limit prints to 600.

```
bacons = 0
while True:
    print "chunky bacon"
    bacons += 1
    if bacons == 600:
        break
```